# Select only the top 1 value from a column in a table that I'm joining?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So below is the query, how can I store only the top 1 "agencyID" into DCA.AgencyID? I know that the way the query below is structured now it would select all the "agencyID" values and not just the top 1.

```
SELECT AP.ID
        ,DCA.AgencyID as agencyID --How to store select top 1?
        ,replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.UserNameWebsite)), '\', '') AS username
        ,replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.FirstName)), '\', '') + N' ' + replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.LastName)), '\', '') AS fullName
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.EmailAddress)) AS email
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.Phone1)) AS phone1
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.Phone2)) AS phone2
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.GreenSolution)) AS greenSolution
        ,CASE 
            WHEN UserType = 'AM'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS producer
    FROM DEV01_DataExchange.[DuckCreek].[fpmAgentsProfile] AP
    Inner Join [DUCKCREEK_DEV].[DEV01_DuckCreek_Consolidated].[dbo].Agency DCA
    on AP.AgencyID = DCA.Reference
    WHERE TransType = 'A' AND DC_LastModifiedDate IS NULL AND DCA.Reference is NOT NULL
```

Comment: How do you define "top 1"? Longest name, biggest budget, etc.

Comment: Use `APPLY` with a query using a `TOP (1)` (and `ORDER BY` of course) instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: What other columns are in the DCA table that would define the 'top 1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but the answer is `cross apply`:

```
FROM DEV01_DataExchange.[DuckCreek].[fpmAgentsProfile] AP CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) DCA.*
      FROM [DUCKCREEK_DEV].[DEV01_DuckCreek_Consolidated].[dbo].Agency DCA
      WHERE AP.AgencyID = DCA.Reference
     ) DCA
WHERE TransType = 'A' AND DC_LastModifiedDate IS NULL AND DCA.Reference is NOT NULL;
```

Normally an `ORDER BY` clause would be used.  Perhaps `ORDER BY DCA.AgencyID DESC`?  However, if there is a column called `AgencyID`, I'm surprised it is not being used for the alignment to `AP`.

Also, some of the `WHERE` conditions might belong in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Cross Apply instead of the Join:

```
SELECT   AP.ID
        ,DCA.AgencyID as agencyID
        ,replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.UserNameWebsite)), '\', '') AS username
        ,replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.FirstName)), '\', '') + N' ' + replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.LastName)), '\', '') AS fullName
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.EmailAddress)) AS email
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.Phone1)) AS phone1
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.Phone2)) AS phone2
        ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AP.GreenSolution)) AS greenSolution
        ,CASE 
            WHEN UserType = 'AM'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS producer
    FROM DEV01_DataExchange.[DuckCreek].[fpmAgentsProfile] AP
    Cross Apply
    (
        Select top 1 AG.*
        From [DUCKCREEK_DEV].[DEV01_DuckCreek_Consolidated].[dbo].Agency AG
        where AG.Reference = AP.AgencyID
    ) DCA
    WHERE TransType = 'A' AND DC_LastModifiedDate IS NULL AND DCA.Reference is NOT NULL
```

Comment: You're missing an `ORDER BY` in the `APPLY`'s subquery.

Comment: @Larnu: Technically, an order by it's not necessary. In this case, it appears that he only needs the first match to get the AgencyId from Agency table.

Comment: It's not necessarily, however, it is required for consistent and reliable results. There is no "first" when you have no order, so what you're returning isn't the "first", but any arbitrary row.